# string match string index out of range

Tags: python, string, string-matching

Could someone please explain to me why this won't work? I could always copy the answer, but then I wouldn't learn why this didn't work.

[a scrrenshot of the problem, my work, and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yCeP.png)

*Given 2 strings, a and b, return the number of the positions where they contain the same length 2 substring. So "xxcaazz" and "xxbaaz" yields 3, since the "xx", "aa", and "az" substrings appear in the same place in both strings.*

```
def string_match(a, b):
  
  count = 0
  
  if len(a) or len(b) == 0:
    return count
  
  else:
  
    if len(a)> len(b):
      for n in range(len(a)-2):
        if a[n]==b[n]:
          count +=1
          
    else:
      for n in range(len(b)-2):
        if b[n]==a[n]:
          count+=1
          
    return count
```

Thank you so much!!

I tried using index locations to find matching characters in 2 strings

Comment: Don't post pictures of code.  That's a big non-no here.  Post the actual code.

Comment: Don't make us retype code from an image.  Please post the code as plain text.

Comment: Will do! Thanks. One second please.

Comment: That having been said, what do you think `if len(a) or len(b) == 0:` does?  Remember, you aren't having a conversation with a person in English.  Instead, it will evaluate that expression, which is an `or` expression.  The first operand is `len(a)`, which is true if `a` has any length greater than zero.  So unless `a` is the empty string, your function will return `0`.  Change it to `if len(a) == 0 or len(b) == 0:`  Or better yet, just delete that entire test.  It serves no purpose.

Comment: The other bug is `range(len(a) - 1)` and `range(len(b) - 1)`.  These are bugs.  All they do is cause it to skip the last character in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the length of the shortest string in the loop. So you should switch your condition

from

```py
if len(a) > len(b):
    for n in range(len(a)-1):
```

to

```py
if len(a) < len(b):
    for n in range(len(a)-1):
```

That's for the `Index out of range` error, yet as mentionned in the comments there are some other bugs in your code

```py
# first condition
if len(a) == 0 or len(b) == 0:
    return 0
```

### Full code

```py
def string_match(a, b):
    count = 0
    
    if len(a) == 0 or len(b) == 0:
        return 0
        
    if len(a) < len(b):
        for n in range(len(a)):
            if a[n] == b[n]:
                count += 1
    else:
        for n in range(len(b)):
            if a[n] == b[n]:
                count += 1
    return count
```

> ***NOTE*** your code does not answer the given task, take your time to develop a better solution

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your help! I made the following adjustments and the code works!

```
def string_match(a, b):
    count = 0
    n=0
    
    if len(a) == 0 or len(b) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
      if len(a) < len(b):
          for n in range(len(a)-1):
              if a[n:n+2] == b[n:n+2]:
                  count += 1
      else:
          for n in range(len(b)-1):
              if a[n:n+2] == b[n:n+2]:
                  count += 1
      return count
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).